# How to find Window by variable title using TestStack.White framework?

Tags: ui-automation, office-automation, white-framework, gui-test-framework

I am using TestStack.White framework to automate opening new document in MS Word 2013.

I am opening Microsoft Word application with:

```
   Application application = Application.Launch("winword.exe");
```

After that, I am trying to get the window by partial title:

```
   Window window = application.GetWindow("Word", InitializeOption.NoCache);
```

But it throws an exception saying that there is no such window.

Window title is: **Document1 - Word**

The question is: How to get a window by partial title taking into consideration that the title is changing every time: "Document2 - Word", "Document3 - Word", etc.

Also tried *Word but looks like this func does not support wildcards

If I invoke:
          List windows = application.GetWindows();
after launching an application, windows list is empty.

Thanks in advance,
Ostap

Answer (score 0):

It looks like opening window takes some noticeable time. GUI testing frameworks often have functions like Wait() to make sure the window is already created/visible/enabled. I'm not an expert in Teststack.White. Probably this document may help: http://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AdvancedTopics/Waiting/

Comment: Waits does not help, window was not found after 30 seconds. Tried to search by title which is 100% on the screen. Also tried sleep for 10 seconds before window search.

Comment: OK, it's Microsoft. :)
How about using COM interop interface and Word object model?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we.aspx

Comment: Another more concrete example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173188(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: thanks for the answer. Microsoft COM works for native controls/workflows. In my case we have a MS Word plugin which hooks and replaces MS dialogs/controls, etc. Need to verify if it will handle such controls

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EnumWindows](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows) to find all the open windows.

Within that callback you'll get a window handle which you can then us with [GetWindowTextLength](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtextlength) and [GetWindowText](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowtext)

This will let you decide what window handle is to the window you want.  From there you can use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowthreadprocessid) to retrieve the process ID for the word document.

And finally with that you can create a TestStack White application using the Application.Start()

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Window GetWindowBySubstring(this Application app, string titleSubString)
{
    return app.GetWindows().FirstOrDefault(w => w.Title.Contains(titleSubString));
}
```